# cannot start Eclipse (2019-12) on a fresh Manjaro installation

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Well, guys,

I am having a little trouble starting eclipse.
Specifically, it crashes on every workspace I tried(I am using backed-up ones from another laptop with manjaro).

At first, Eclipse just displayed all the buttons just under the top bar wrongly.
I thought it might have to do with my java version(I used Java13), so I changed it to java8.

Unfortunately, it won't start any workspace I choose at all now.

The only thing I get is the log in .metadata.
Furthermore, I tried with --clean and put the results in a file as well.

As the terminal results of the --clean try are smaller I will put them down there.
If you like I'll be glad to put the .metadata/log up here as well. It's just really long and I haven't found how to upload a text file yet(*sweatdrop).

Here are the terminal results:

```
OT/Equinox: Using weaving scheme OTDRE as detected from class org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.hierarchy.OTTypeHierarchies
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
11:01:01,719 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[client] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:01:01,719 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[client] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:01:01,719 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[client] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
11:01:01,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[client] - Setting up default configuration.
11:01:01,821 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:01:01,826 |-WARN in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Due to missing top level configuration file, automatic reconfiguration is impossible.
11:01:01,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
11:01:01,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:01:01,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
11:01:01,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:01:01,872 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:01:01,875 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
11:01:01,890 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@12f40c8a - Will use zip compression
11:01:01,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:01:01,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: /home/jonasenxing/.jubula/logs/client.log
11:01:01,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [/home/jonasenxing/.jubula/logs/client.log]
11:01:01,901 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
11:01:01,901 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
11:01:01,901 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:01:01,901 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@12c14bc5 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Best wishes! I hope to hear from you soon!

Here is some sparse additional information(though I doubt it helps much):
This manjaro arch installation was created and installed on 21. January. I used the Gnome version and since then I only installed Java8 java13 Eclipse and Gummi(as the LaTeX Editor).

I'll gladly answer any additional questions you may have.

And here is the reduced log file:

```
!SESSION 2020-01-23 12:16:06.143 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.14.0.I20191210-0610
java.version=1.8.0_232
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product --clean
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product --clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:07.778
!MESSAGE Error activating OT/Equinox: Agent class org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.OTEquinoxAgent was not installed. OT/Equinox will be desabled.
If this happens during the restart after installing OT/Equinox, please exit Eclipse and perform a fresh start.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:07.780
!MESSAGE Error activating OT/Equinox: Agent class org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.OTEquinoxAgent was not installed. OT/Equinox will be desabled.
If this happens during the restart after installing OT/Equinox, please exit Eclipse and perform a fresh start.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:08.581
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui:3.4.200.v20180302-2006 (1049)[org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery(75)] : bind method [bindRemoteServiceAdmin] not found; Component will fail

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:08.582
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui:3.4.200.v20180302-2006 (1049)[org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery(75)] : bind method [bindRemoteServiceAdmin] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.652
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.

Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.655
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.

Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.passage.lic.features.migration 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.658
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.passage.lic.features.migration:0.5.0.v20191203-0807 (2604)BundleComponentActivator : Unexpected failure enabling component holder org.eclipse.passage.lic.internal.features.migration.FeaturesMigrator
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EPackage


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.passage.lic.licenses.migration 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.717
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.passage.lic.licenses.migration:0.5.0.v20191203-0807 (2613)BundleComponentActivator : Unexpected failure enabling component holder org.eclipse.passage.lic.internal.licenses.migration.LicensesMigrator
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EPackage

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.passage.lic.products.migration 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.728
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.passage.lic.products.migration:0.5.0.v20191203-0807 (2621)BundleComponentActivator : Unexpected failure enabling component holder org.eclipse.passage.lic.internal.products.migration.ProductsMigrator
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EPackage

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.passage.lic.users.migration 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:09.734
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.passage.lic.users.migration:0.5.0.v20191203-0807 (2627)BundleComponentActivator : Unexpected failure enabling component holder org.eclipse.passage.lic.internal.users.migration.UsersMigrator
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EPackage

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:14.986
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.


!ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:15.093
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui:3.4.200.v20180302-2006 (1049)[org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery(75)] : unbind method [unbindRemoteServiceAdmin] not found; Component will fail

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:15.093
!MESSAGE bundle org.eclipse.ecf.remoteservice.ui:3.4.200.v20180302-2006 (1049)[org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery(75)] : unbind method [unbindRemoteServiceAdmin] not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core 4 0 2020-01-23 12:16:15.278
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.P2CorePlugin$Implementation.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/Resource

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.

Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/Resource

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore (206).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation$Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (163).

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.
```

Comment: You've created a great first post. Pleas provide more Information to your operating system. This might help to find an an solution

Comment: When I upgraded to Eclipse 2019-12 I faced several issues on Windows. I had to revert to the previous version. Maybe it is also buggy on Linux.

Comment: @AndiCover Which issues? Where are the bug reports? I use Eclipse 2019-12 on Windows 10 without problems.

Comment: Please delete the `.log` file and reproduce the issue to get a minimal log file for this issue.

Comment: Hello AndiCover, I have the same Eclipse-Version on another Laptop with the same OS. It works completely fine, though I will try and look for some information in this direction.

Comment: Hi again, the newly generated log file has about 1400 lines. I have cut out the stacktraces and reduced it to 180 lines. If you need them though I still ahve the original file.

Comment: The log file shows also that you have installed [Object teams](https://www.eclipse.org/objectteams/) which is not contained in the Eclipse Java IDE package. Can you reproduce the issue with a new workspace (`-data <path-to-empty-directory-that-should-be-used-as-workspace>`? Can you reproduce the issue with the Eclipse Java IDE without additional plug-ins? Please try both.

Comment: Hmm. I cannot reproduce the issue with an empty directory. Though now the buttons and at least the Task List is not displayed correctly again. That however might be another issue, so I will not upload the screenshot as of yet. First I'd like to be able to open my old workspaces.

Comment: I will try disabling any plug-ins in the new workspace now

Comment: Alright. The Plugins seem to be the problems, because icons and such are displayed correctly now.

Comment: After disabling them and taking greater care, all seems to be okay. Thank you for your great help!